# mysql: multi slave replication but one slave to replicate only single table of specific database

Tags: mysql

Innodb table to be more specific.
Setup would be one master and two slaves.  One of the slaves would only be replicating a single table on a specific database while the other slave replicates two full dbs.

Is this possible?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Use this option in the slave's my.cnf

```
    --replicate-do-table=db_name.tbl_name
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table

Comment: Straightforward and concise. +1 for brevity !!!

Comment: "Each slave receives the entire binary log but processess.." Isn't this a huge waste of data (expensive in AWS) for servers with HUGE (GBs in a day) binlogs? Is there a way to configure the master not to send this data to specific slaves?